# how to pause animation in multiple elements on hover on one element?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to stop animation in custom marquee, When i hover on one element of the marquee, 
**NOTE** marquee consists of 2 content so that it become in a loop and don't start from over.

here is my code:

```
<div className="cg-container large" style={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'}}>
  <div className="cg-widget">
    <div className="cg-marquee">
      <span id="stop-anima" className="cg-marquee-content-1">
        <div className="cg-flex cg-flex-row">
          <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/resource_redirect?locale=en&amp;route=coins/bitcoin&amp;utm_source=www.coingecko.com&amp;utm_medium=coin_price_marquee_widget&amp;utm_content=bitcoin" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" className="cg-py-2 cg-px-3 cg-flex cg-coin-row cg-sm">
            <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
              <img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579" alt="BTC" className="cg-mr-2"/>
              <span><span className="cg-bold">Bitcoin</span> (BTC)</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-flex cg-justify-end cg-items-center cg-primary-color-dark">
              <div style={{marginLeft: '20px'}} >
                <span className="cg-bold">$3,825.97</span><span>(0.45%)</span>
              </div>
              <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-arrow-up"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
            <a href="/" className="cg-bold cg-sm cg-px-3">NEXT CONTENT OF MARQUEE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span id="stop-anima" className="cg-marquee-content-2">
        <div className="cg-flex cg-flex-row">
          <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/resource_redirect?locale=en&amp;route=coins/bitcoin&amp;utm_source=www.coingecko.com&amp;utm_medium=coin_price_marquee_widget&amp;utm_content=bitcoin" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" className="cg-py-2 cg-px-3 cg-flex cg-coin-row cg-sm">
            <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
              <img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579" alt="BTC" className="cg-mr-2"/>
              <span><span className="cg-bold">Bitcoin</span> (BTC)</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-flex cg-justify-end cg-items-center cg-primary-color-dark">
              <div style={{marginLeft: '20px'}} >
                <span className="cg-bold">$3,825.97</span><span>(0.45%)</span>
              </div>
              <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-arrow-up"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
            <a href="/" className="cg-bold cg-sm cg-px-3">NEXT CONTENT OF MARQUEE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is css part to pause

```
#stop-anima:hover {
 -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused;
 }
```

And when i tried using `id="stop-anima"` or `className` the result was one element stop **AKA** content1 for example , but the other element keeps going and animation doesn't pause. can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the issue , i reached to conclusion that , i'm using reactjs why i don't use it.
so i solved the issue following 2 steps

**1.** updated my component state to have a key of `mouseEnter: {}`

**2.** Write 2 handlers to handle 2 events `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` in the parent `<div>`

That's it, all i needed to do so here is the final code: i reached

```
this.state = {
 mouseEnter:{}
}

handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      mouseEnter: {
        animationPlayState: 'paused'
      }
    })
  }

  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      mouseEnter: {}
    })
  }

<div className="cg-container large" style={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'}}>
  <div className="cg-widget">
    <div onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} className="cg-marquee">
      <span style={this.state.mouseEnter} className="cg-marquee-content-1">
        <div className="cg-flex cg-flex-row">
          <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/resource_redirect?locale=en&amp;route=coins/bitcoin&amp;utm_source=www.coingecko.com&amp;utm_medium=coin_price_marquee_widget&amp;utm_content=bitcoin" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" className="cg-py-2 cg-px-3 cg-flex cg-coin-row cg-sm">
            <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
              <img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579" alt="BTC" className="cg-mr-2"/>
              <span><span className="cg-bold">Bitcoin</span> (BTC)</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-flex cg-justify-end cg-items-center cg-primary-color-dark">
              <div style={{marginLeft: '20px'}} >
                <span className="cg-bold">$3,825.97</span><span>(0.45%)</span>
              </div>
              <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-arrow-up"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
            <a href="/" className="cg-bold cg-sm cg-px-3">NEXT CONTENT OF MARQUEE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span style={this.state.mouseEnter} className="cg-marquee-content-2">
        <div className="cg-flex cg-flex-row">
          <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/resource_redirect?locale=en&amp;route=coins/bitcoin&amp;utm_source=www.coingecko.com&amp;utm_medium=coin_price_marquee_widget&amp;utm_content=bitcoin" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" className="cg-py-2 cg-px-3 cg-flex cg-coin-row cg-sm">
            <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
              <img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579" alt="BTC" className="cg-mr-2"/>
              <span><span className="cg-bold">Bitcoin</span> (BTC)</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-flex cg-justify-end cg-items-center cg-primary-color-dark">
              <div style={{marginLeft: '20px'}} >
                <span className="cg-bold">$3,825.97</span><span>(0.45%)</span>
              </div>
              <div className="cg-ml-2 cg-arrow-up"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div className="cg-flex cg-items-center">
            <a href="/" className="cg-bold cg-sm cg-px-3">NEXT CONTENT OF MARQUEE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```